# Paypal checkout - Removing VAT to Israel non-residents

Tags: drupal, paypal

Israel non-residents that are purchasing israeli product (VAT included) in drupal store, Should not be obliged to pay VAT. is there a way to remove VAT cost to these users on PAYPAL checkout (express / credit-card)?

Comment: have you refer [this](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Selling-on-your-website/Remove-VAT-from-some-of-my-PayPal-buttons/td-p/316396?profile.language=en-gb)